# the wx.EVT_MOTION event doesn't work for wxPython 4.0.6

Tags: python, wxpython

the event wx.EVT_MOTION doesn't work for wxPython 4.0.6

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion, self.GetGridWindow())
```

with wxPython 3.0.2.0 the same binding worked. I also tried to bind other events e.g. EVT_MOUSEWHEEL for wxPython 4.0.6 and it worked. Does anyone know what changed in the version 4.0.6 and why the wx.EVT_MOTION isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it change anything if you do:

self.GetGridWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)

?

Comment: If you specify the grid's name i.e. `self.mygrid.GetGridWindow().Bind(bla bla)` it works a charm